# How to reload an altered image on slider-onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

so my problem is that I can't seem to figure out why my program won't load the altered image.

The ajax call to "/Contours" triggers a flask app.route where the image-alteration happens.
There the image is saved under the same name again so the old version is overwritten.
That part works as it should.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("rangevalue_low").value = document.getElementById("thresh_low").value;
    document.getElementById("rangevalue_high").value = document.getElementById("thresh_high").value;

    function render() {
        let range_low = document.getElementById("rangevalue_low").value;
        let range_high = document.getElementById("rangevalue_high").value;

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Contours",
            data: {
                'imagePath': 'static/images/kittens/kittens-2.jpg',
                'thresh_low': range_low,
                'thresh_high': range_high
            },
            method: 'POST'
        })
        .done(() => {
            $("#outlined_image").attr("src", "");


            setTimeout(() => {
                let source = "../static/output/result.jpg";
                $("#outlined_image").attr({"src": source, "class": "img_result"});
            }, 2000)

        })
    }
</script>
```

The triggering of altering the image and calling the render-function works, but for some reason the image doesn't update but always keeps the same one, even though the path to the image now leads to a new image.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely a caching issue because, although the content of the image has changed, the URI is the same.

To force the image to be reloaded you could append a timestamp to the URL:

```
let source = "../static/output/result.jpg?" + (new Date()).getTime();
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you so much!
How does the timestamp affect it though?

Comment: It works because the browser caches content based on its URI. Appending the timestamp each time you request the image makes the browser believe it's a new image for every request and so forces it to be downloaded again instead of read from the cache.

Comment: No problem, glad to help